# Error loading truck with pallets on a certain dock

Tags: anylogic

I would like to load my trucks on certain docks (for example truck A on dock 50) to a certain time. So I create a dbase which gives the different docks an id and connect it with my truck arrival dbase. So in my example my trucks should all arrive at dock 6 to different times. After that I load the dbase to my population loadDocks. Since I implemented this I get the attached error.

[dock_dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVyX8.png)

[agent_dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ia7.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ0Ga.png)

[population_loadDocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJo1e.png)

[arrivaltime_dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpWRH.png)

Comment: the error is in the "spaceAvailable" function. Please check there and show us the code (and the exact line causing the NPE). Also, do study how to handle such errors and find the root cause from those (rather cryptic) errors :)

Comment: return storage.capacity() - storage.size() - reserved.size(); 
  }

void reserve( Pallet p ) { 

reserved.add(p); 
  }
void unreserve( Pallet p ) { 

reserved.remove(p);   The function works before I implemented the database..

Comment: And *where* is the NPE caused? You need to be able to track your actual errors, else it is impossible for anyone to help ;-) Likely, some element is not filled with an object but "null" and you call it nonetheless. Find that element and either fill it with something or change the code so you account for the element being null. (if xxx == null ... else ...)